# Stretching a WPF Canvas Horizontally

Tags: wpf, silverlight, canvas, wpf-controls, stretch

How do I make a `Canvas` stretch fully horizontally with variable width?  This is the parent `Canvas`, so it has no parents, only children.

XAML Source: it displays in blend
http://resopollution.com/xaml.txt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a `Grid` as the top level element in your UI - it'll stretch to fill its container.  Then put a `Canvas` with `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` inside the `Grid` and it'll behave the way you want.

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Canvas Background="Blue"/>
</Grid>
```

That worked for me.  The key is your top level UI element.  While a `Grid` fills all available space by default, `Canvas`es take up only as much room as their contents demand.

Comment: Do you know if the "x:Class=" attribute is necessary?  I tried using Grid as containment but for some reason everything just disappears.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Canvas.Resources>

This did not work for me =(

Comment: How are you testing?  I pasted this into kaxaml and it works for me, so you don't need the x:class attribute:

<Grid
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Canvas Background="Blue"/>
</Grid>

Comment: Oh, and this shows the HorizontalAlignment=Stretch isn't necessary either.

Comment: Hmm, your example works if I just use your code, but when I try to wrap my entire code for the video player and preview in browser inside of a GRID tag, everything just disappears.  I only see a white background.  No XAML errors either.

Comment: Could you post a full example of the Xaml that's not functional?  The Xaml in the first post looks incomplete but if I could repro the error I might be able to help.

Comment: First of all, nice player!  The problem (which was a "duh" moment for me after re-reading your question) is that the root element is a canvas.  I took the code you posted and set the parent canvas background to blue for testing.  Then, I wrapped that canvas in a parent grid and removed its width and height properties.  At that point I saw a small black media player at the top left of the screen and the rest of the screen filled with blue.  Canvases don't stretch to fill the parent automatically *unless* you place one in a Grid. By default they're only the size of their inner content. Hth!

Comment: So to get the video to display at the bigger size, I'd have to put every single canvas inside a <grid>?

Comment: I think I found the solution, in addition to what you said, I added a VerticalAlignment="Top" and HorizontalAlignment="Left" to the canvas inside of the outer grid and everything magically worked.  Totally random but your comments helped guide the way :D

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you've tried 
`canvas.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch`

If this doesn't work, then what you could do is bind the `Width` and `Height` properties of the canvas to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties of the containing window.

Comment: canvas.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch is done inside the C# code?  I only have access to XAML.

Also I don't have a containing Window either =(.  Whenver I do the Binding Element, my silverlight app crashes.

Comment: A little late, but for anyone with the same issue: ``<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">`` in the XAML code worked just fine in my case. And it saves you from boxing every canvas into a grid (especially if you have many of them).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dock panel to get it to fill the available width.  The last item in a dock panel list of controls is automatically stretched to fill the remaining space.

```
<DockPanel>
   <Canvas />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Is there any quick way to do it for the <Canvas> tag?

Comment: I tried removing the Height and Width property but everything just disappears.

Answer (score 1):

The canvas should do this automatically, unless you are manually setting the height and/or width. What kind of control are you trying to place the canvas on? Can you post your code?

Comment: I've posted my code.  The Canvas is the main parent element of the entire application.

Comment: I tried removing the Height and Width property but everything just disappears.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're specifying the `Height` and `Width`.  Without these properties, the control may appear to vanish in the designer, but it should size appropriately when you insert the canvas into another control.

If I recall correctly, the next version of WPF will have 'DesignWidth' and 'DesignHeight' properties that allow you to show the control in the designer with a given size without effecting it's measurement when inserted into other controls.